# Why do watershed function from scikit-image does not work when my seed points are exactly as large as the vessels I want to fill

Tags: python, scikit-image, watershed

Ok here is the situation, I want to make a watershed of this binary vessels image.

[Binary vessels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lH2mT.png).

I want to use these colored vessels as seed points for the algorithm.

[Seed points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUoZj.png)

It seems that when I use the raw colored image, the watershed does not go further than the colored image.

The goal is to have this image.
[Filled binary vessels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyTKI.png)

The code use is this one

```
distances = distance_transform_edt(vessels)
segmentation = watershed(-distances, markers, mask=vessels).
```

The only solution that I found was to erode markers data (the 1st colored image).

Do you guys have a solution why watershed do this ? We even try the same code on other computers and it works find without erosion.

Edit:

Here is an image of the distances. When I take the negative, every 1 become -1. So the highest values in the image become 0.

[image: distances image]

Comment: Do you know if the algorithm you use floods the whole image or only from the markers? The markers are usually small points, not complete regions. Could you please post the image of the distance transform?

Comment: You should provide a short reproducing example. Using regions as markers shouldn't be a problem, but you will never achieve the desired results (if your image is 2D) because there are some disconnected components (dark green, and some other lone pixels).

Comment: Ok, so my images are in 3D. I just did a maximum intensity projection to visualize it in 2D.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to the scikit-image thread of SO! Below is a small reproducible example showing that the watershed behaves nicely even with touching markers.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage import segmentation
from scipy import ndimage

img = np.zeros((20, 20), dtype=np.bool)
img[3:-3, 3:-3] = True

distance = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(img)

markers = np.zeros_like(img, dtype=np.uint8)
markers[7:-7, 5:10] = 1
markers[7:-7, 10:15] = 2

ws = segmentation.watershed(-distance, markers, mask=img)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3)
ax[0].imshow(img)
ax[1].imshow(markers)
ax[2].imshow(ws)
plt.show()
```

Could it happen that the non-labeled vessel pixels in your markers array are not set to 0 but 1 instead? The watershed only labels 0-valued pixels.

A reproducible standalone script could help, the different images you linked to had different dimensions so it was hard to work from them.

Finally, you could be interested here in trying the [random walker algorithm](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_random_walker_segmentation.html) which can produce really good results for images such as your (no strong gradients between the regions you want to separate).